# how to remove the "data resource construction notebook" banner from a notebook

Tags: notebooks, user-interface

At some point, today, I pressed a key combination that made the "Data Resource Construction Notebook" banner to appear at the top of the notebook. This is taking way too much screen space and I didn't ask to store anything on the Wolfram could.

This banner shows in only one notebook. I could not find any ways to removing this banner apart from copying everything in another new notebook. Can anyone tell how to remove this banner.
[image: This is the banner]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]
```

or select StyleSheet >> Default from the Format menu.